# How to know if a WKWebView is redirecting due to a user interaction?

Tags: swift, redirect, wkwebview

I'm working with WKWebView and I need to execute some code when the user does something that cause the WKWebView to go to another url (e.g. click on a button in the WKWebView which leads to another url). I was trying to do it with comparing the working url with the original one, but some redirection are not caused my the user but the website itself. Is there anyway to differentiate? Here is what I have now:

```
func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didCommit navigation: WKNavigation!) {

    print(webView.url?.absoluteString)

    if webView.url?.absoluteString != self.workingReult {
        //do something
    }

}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

sure. Here is my solution for Swift 4.

Once you set the navigationDelegate for the WKWebView, you can implement the following function which is called anytime the web view is navigating:

```
func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, decidePolicyFor navigationAction: WKNavigationAction, decisionHandler: @escaping (WKNavigationActionPolicy) -> Void) {
    if navigationAction.navigationType == .linkActivated { 
        //Tap on href link case
        decisionHandler(WKNavigationActionPolicy.cancel)
    } else { 
        //Any other case
        decisionHandler(WKNavigationActionPolicy.allow)
    }
}
```

As you can see you can get the trigger of the navigation action using **navigationAction.navigationType**. In my case I'm preventing the user from navigating the links but you can customize it as you like.

Remember that the decisionHandler must be included for any case.

You can check the rest of WKNavigationType constant cases [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/webkit/wknavigationtype)

Answer (score 1):

To see redirect URL, check URL from `navigationAction` instead of `webview.url` like this way.

```
    override internal func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, decidePolicyFor navigationAction: WKNavigationAction, decisionHandler: @escaping (WKNavigationActionPolicy) -> Void) {
    super.webView(webView, decidePolicyFor: navigationAction, decisionHandler: decisionHandler)
    let request = navigationAction.request
    if let url = request.url {
    //here you can compare your url
    }

}
```

Comment: How does this answer the question?
`decidePolicyFor` is fired for all requests including assets (css, js), ajax requests ...

Answer (score 0):

You can use either of this,

```
 func webView(webView: WKWebView, didFinishNavigation navigation: WKNavigation!) {
    let currentURL : NSString = (webView.URL!.host)!
    //print("The current String is\(currentURL)")
    if currentURL.containsString("test.com") 
    {
   //handle your actions here
    }
    print("finish to load")
   }
```

Or you can use this compare your url

```
func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, decidePolicyFor navigationAction: WKNavigationAction, decisionHandler: @escaping (WKNavigationActionPolicy) -> Void) {
let app = UIApplication.sharedApplication()
let url = navigationAction.request.URL
//handle your events from here
}
```